# Is it haram for me to take these awards?

Tags: halal-haram, riba, money, music

Assalamualaikum,

Earlier this year i took part at a project in my school. We had to make a video about a certain profession and the video I made also has background music. Now, months later it turns out I've won the competition and they're giving us money and free practice at a tech company as a reward. However, I've repented for using music on that video since music is prohibited and my question is: Is it haram for me to take those rewards?

Please respond, Jazakallah Khair.

Answer (score -1):

Wa 'alayk as-salam,

Since the activity/competition was something haram, then taking the prize money is also haram, I would simply try to refuse it, you won so it's your choice, they shouldn't be able to just forcibly give you the money against your will..

As for practice at the tech company; if there is nothing haram involved then it's your choice

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification for the purposes of improving the post they're on, not for argument and debate or extended discussion of tangential points.